# Sums and Joins not correct

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, one with a list of products, and one a checkout table.

I've written this query:

```
SELECT tblComponents.Name, tblComponents.Tax, 
SUM(CONVERT(int,ProductCheckout.ItemQuantity)) as Quantity
FROM tblComponents
INNER JOIN ProductCheckout
ON tblComponents.ID=ProductCheckout.ItemID where tblComponents.Tax <> 0
Group BY tblComponents.Name, ProductCheckout.ItemQuantity, tblComponents.Tax;
```

I'm looking to get the total number/quantity of items ordered.

Currently it shows

```
OrderName   2.00    1
OrderName   2.00    2
```

I want it to show:

```
OrderName   4       3
```

I'm looking to get a list of all the product names, with the sum of the taxes and quantity ordered.

I'm not sure what is wrong with this query, but I need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You need to `sum (tblComponents.Tax)` and remove it from the group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you shouldn't be including `ProductCheckout.ItemQuantity` or `tblComponents.Tax` in the `Group By` clause and you should be summing the `tblComponents.Tax` column. Something like:

```
SELECT tblComponents.Name, SUM(tblComponents.Tax), 
       SUM(CONVERT(int,ProductCheckout.ItemQuantity)) as Quantity
FROM tblComponents
INNER JOIN ProductCheckout 
    ON tblComponents.ID=ProductCheckout.ItemID where tblComponents.Tax <> 0
Group BY tblComponents.Name;
```